# Удаление куки mybb_ru с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, cookie

Есть форум на 0pk. Надо реализовать кнопку "удаление куков". Проблема в том, что javascript почему-то не удаляет куку с именим mybb_ru. Даже считать не может.

```
writeCookie("mybb_ru","")

function writeCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure)    { 
  document.cookie= name + "=" + value +
   ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires : "") +
   ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
   ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
  ((secure) ? "' secure" : "")
}

readCookie("mybb_ru")

function readCookie(name)   { 
  var prefix = name + "="
  var cookieStartIndex = document.cookie.indexOf(prefix) 
  if (cookieStartIndex == -1) {
    document.write("нет куки с именем "+name+"<br>");
    return null
  } 
  var cookieEndIndex = document.cookie.indexOf(";", cookieStartIndex + prefix.length) 
  if (cookieEndIndex == -1)
    cookieEndIndex = document.cookie.length
  return unescape(document.cookie.substring(cookieStartIndex + prefix.length, cookieEndIndex))
}
```

Эти ф-и не работают.

Тоже не пашет. Тупо скопированная ф-я. Выполняется (через firebug слежу), но кука никак не изменяется.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload= function(){
  setCookie("mybb_ru", null, { expires: -1 })
}
function setCookie(name, value, props) {
  props = props || {}
    var exp = props.expires
if (typeof exp == "number" && exp) {
      var d = new Date()
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + exp*1000)
  exp = props.expires = d
    }
if(exp && exp.toUTCString) { props.expires = exp.toUTCString() }     
value = encodeURIComponent(value)
var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value
for(var propName in props){
  updatedCookie += "; " + propName
  var propValue = props[propName]
      if(propValue !== true){ updatedCookie += "=" + propValue }
    }
    document.cookie = updatedCookie
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload= function(){
  setCookie("mybb_ru", '122', { expires: 100 });
}
function setCookie(name, value, props) {
  props = props || {};
    var exp = props.expires;
if (typeof exp == "number" && exp) {
      var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + exp*1000);
  exp = props.expires = d;
    }
if(exp && exp.toUTCString) { props.expires = exp.toUTCString(); }     
value = encodeURIComponent(value);
var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value;
for(var propName in props){
  updatedCookie += "; " + propName;
  var propValue = props[propName];
      if(propValue !== true){ updatedCookie += "=" + propValue; }
    }
    document.cookie = updatedCookie;
} 
  alert(document.cookie);

</script>
```

Если честно, я не отследил, где ошибка, но мораль проста: в конце каждой операции нужна точка с запятой. Думаю, этого кода достаточно для решения вашей проблемы? ;)

Comment: Наверное, я полный идиот. Не работает.
document.cookie пустое значение

Comment: Вставьте этот код на пустую страницу и обновите ее несколько раз - куки меняются при следующей загрузке страницы. Если на отдельной странице работает, а у вас - нет, проверьте, код до и после данного. Особое внимание тому, что "болтается" на window.onload .

Answer (score 0):

Не то, что считать - установить не может. Попробуйте [эти функции](http://javascript.ru/unsorted/top-10-functions#3-2-i-1-getcookie-setcookie-deletecookie).

Comment: Не пашет. Обновил вопрос, а то не влезает в комент.

Answer (score 0):

Проверил все приведенные кода. И как не странно всё работает на ура.
Куки перезаписываются как и нужно. 
**Сhubrick** проверь может у тебя где нить после данного кода есть ещё JS который всё и портачит. Запусти функцию изменения куки и отслеживай алертом каждый шаг.